# Random function in C

Tags: c

I need a random function for number betwen 11 and 99. I wrote this:

```
int random (void){
    int i2;
    i2=11+(rand()%99);      
    return i2;
}
```

but the numbers go over 99. Why?

Comment: What if `rand()` returns 98 ?

Comment: my outputs were:52
64
108
78
73
93
104
65
45

Comment: Downvoters: The OP showed **effort** - he did try his own code. His question is **clear**. It is also **useful** for other beginners. The fact that he might be new to programming is really no reason for downvoting.

Comment: +1 for the comment of @amit. +1 for the question, because of the down-votes. This could be very demotivating ..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because if `rand()` return `98`, then `98 % 99` is `98` and `98 + 11 > 99`.

To do this, you need

```
i2 = 11 + ( rand() % 89 );
```

`rand() % 89` will give you numbers `[0, 88]`, so `+11` would become `[11, 99]`.

---

By the way, don't forget to `srand( time( NULL ) )`, otherwise it will (most probably) generate the same sequence of (pseudo) random numbers all the time.

Comment: To OP, this is not a fully uniform distribution. Please take note.

Comment: what do I do withs rand( time( NULL ) )  ?

Comment: @user1601731 - here's an useful link: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/misc/random.html - in other words, you just need to call in somewhere, to be able to generate different sequences of (pseudo)random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

( value % 100 ) is in the range 0 to 99. You add 11 so the range is in 11 to 110.

try something like this:

```
int random (int min,int max){
    return min+(rand()%(max-min));
}
```

the arguments min and max indicate the range of the numbers

Comment: You forgot to add 1 in the last expression. It should be `rand()%(max-min+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `rand()%99` return a value between 0 and 98; then you add 11 so the range is 11 to 109.
You must change 99 with 89

Comment: his range is between 11 and 109. you forgot the 11 at the beginning of the range.